# Ripple effect on white tabLayout

Tags: android, material-design, android-tablayout

Ripple Effect on android tabs is by default in white color. I want to add a ripple effect on `tablayout` but my tabs background is white already and the ripple effect is invisible on it.

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/white"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:tabBackground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:tabTextColor="#222"
            />
```

Is there a way to change color of tabLayout ripple effect so it could be seen even in white background?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44083507/android-bottom-navigation-bar-customization/44083789#44083789

Comment: @NileshRathod I tried it and it's not working for me

Comment: Can you please add a video or gif how it's working now? And also in which version of OS you're testing? Because the same I have tested and it is working as expected.

Comment: Did you check my answer?did it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set background using **app:tabBackground** in TabLayout tag.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_selector_ripple">
```

tab_selector_ripple.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="#0e0e0e">
    <item android:drawable="@color/white" />

</ripple>
```

Let me know if you have more queries regarding this?